# Use Mongoose to connect Node App to MongoDB Replica Set using /etc/hosts (& AWS OpsWorks)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, hosts, aws-opsworks

I'm using Mongoose to connect my Node application to MongoDB. I'm also using AWS OpsWorks to manage my stack, which keeps the /etc/hosts file up to date for me. I currently have a replicaset of 3 mongod instances running, all listed in etc/hosts.

```
0.0.0.1 mongodb1.localdomain mongodb1
0.0.0.2 mongodb2.localdomain mongodb2
0.0.0.3 mongodb3.localdomain mongodb3
```

Per the [Mongoose Docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html), I can connect to the replicaset using the following connection string:

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://mongodb1:27017,mongodb2:27017,mongodb3:27017');
```

But how can I dynamically read the /etc/hosts file and update the connection string if I add/subtract mongod instances to the replicaset?